# How can I automate the removal of XML Documentation Comments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does someone have a script or snippet for Visual Studio that automatically removes comment headers for functions or classes?

I want to remove comments like.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

Actually anything that removes comments starting with /// would really help. We have projects with massive amount of GhostDoc comment that really just hides the code and we are not using the document output. It is a tedious work for us to remove theese comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Quick Replace` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) in Visual Studio and replace `:b+///.*\n` with an empty string (ensure you set `Use` to `Regular expressions`). This should allow you to get rid of the comments in the specified scope.

Comment: That works just great! Changed the regex statement to `[ \t]*///.*\n` so that it works with leading whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Regex `\/\/\/.*<summary>.*<\/summary>`, with these options `gms`, to match the string. You can replace that with nothing. This can be done in Notepad++ or Visual Studio.

Here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/vR0tP6) to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python (with regexps, if you wish):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print( "Usage: removelines <source-file>" )
    exit(0)
InFileName = sys.argv[1]
Out = open( InFileName + ".out", "w" );
for Line in open( InFileName ).readlines():
    if Line.lstrip().find( "///" ) == 0:
        print( "Skipping line", Line )
        continue
    Out.write( Line )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use find and replace in files in Notepad++ (or any other advanced text editor) using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do find and replace with an empty string in visual studio. You already have the strings you want to get rid of. You could also parse the code files as text and remove any line that starts with a comment character.